# Aggregate LINQ results

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

If I have a Publisher table that has many Books, and each Book can have many Authors, how do I get a list of distinct Authors for a Publisher? In SQL you would just join all the tables, select the Author, and use SELECT DISTINCT. Using LINQ I end up with an IEnumerable(Of EntitySet(of Author)):

```
Dim temp = From p in Publishers Select (From b in p.Books Select b.Author)
```

and this still doesn't address duplicate Authors.

Is there a way to get a flat list of Authors, ungrouped from the Books, in a single query? I know I could loop through the sets and create one list and use Distinct on that. I was curious if it could be done in one statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the original query.

```
var authorSets = Publishers
  .Where(...)
  .Select(p => p.Books.Select(b => b.Author));
```

And here is the same query improved by SelectMany to flatten the hierarchy.

```
var authors = Publishers
  .Where(...)
  .SelectMany(p => p.Books.Select(b => b.Author))
  .Distinct();
```

For more information: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548748.aspx)

Comment: SelectMany is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: If GroupBy is my duct tape, then SelectMany is my chainsaw.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work:

In C#:

```
var publisherAuthors = Authors.Where(a => a.Books.Where(b => b.Publisher.Name.Equals("Some Publisher")));
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, although is a bit squished to get it on one line.
Would suggest its split up, or changed into query syntax to make it more readable IMO

Comment: Books.Where() returns an IQueryable<Book>.  Authors.Where() needs a boolean - not an IQueryable<Book>.  Did you mean to use Books.Any() ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are more comfortable with SQL than lambda expression, try:

```
from b in Books 
join ba in BookAuthorIndexes on b.BookId equals ba.BookId 
join a in Authors on ba.AuthorId equals a.AuthorId 
where b.Publisher.Name = "foo" 
select a distinct
```

I'm making some pretty big assumptions about your schema here, but something along those lines.